# Left mouse is held down after single click, but only in certain programs (RStudio)

Tags: mouse, touchpad, dell, rstudio

I'm using a 2016 Dell XPS 13 9350 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

For some reason, when I'm using RStudio, and I left-click inside the editor or console windows, my mouse acts as if I'm holding down the left mouse button (starts selecting a block of text as I move the mouse around). Has anyone else encountered this issue?

I have tried:

- Restarting
- Disconnecting my mouse and using touchpad, same issue
- Disabling touchpad in settings and using only external mouse

This behaviour has not happened in other software, or the native ubuntu environment! Am I missing something stupid here?

Thanks!